# How do you make a single-page-application (SPA) searchable from SharePoint?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, search, sharepoint, single-page-application

We are working on a single-page-application (SPA) developed in ASP.NET MVC using knouckout and a wealth of other libraries. Routing will be done in front-end, maybe we will use [crossroads.js](https://millermedeiros.github.io/crossroads.js/). A lot of information is presented in virtual grids using [slickgrid.js](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid). All data is fetched from backend using AJAX.

Now, if you want to crawl and index such a site from SharePoint, how would you go about that? If you just load the main page with no javascript, it is almost empty.

## Update

After more investigation into this issue, I have concluded that there are at least two possible solutions to this kind of problem.

#### Possible solution 1: Render HTML

This approach would involve detecting that a SP crawler is crawling your site, and then return static HTML pages for the crawler. [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) could possibly be used for this. There are however several uncertain aspects to this solution, and I suspect that it would involve a lot of work.

#### Possible solution 2: Import data into SharePoint

As so clearly described by Josh below, you could import the data that you want crawlable into SharePoint. Then SharePoint can be configured to crawl the data, and the data is not Javascript dependant anymore as it is inside SharePoint. I think this is the best and easiest solution and will mark Josh answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: I understand if this question comes about as a bit too open-ended for stackoverflow, but information about this subject is really hard to find and it do boils down to a specific technical problem. Google has published [this article](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more) but if SharePoint support that is unclear according as to what I have found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I see that this question is getting a lot of close requests, I did run across this very question on a previous project.  Sharepoint won't be able to index the page that data is manipulated on via your SPA, but inside SP, you can connect external data sources into the search service, thus exposing the data inside the SPA.  You would then write custom search results tied to the content type of the data exposed in order to make the results a bit more friendly than just a data row.  You might create an entry point in your SPA that can take in a URL with a parameter so you can send the user from the search results to the SPA in one shot.

There are a lot of interconnected concepts to this solution, so I'd suggest looking into connecting external data sources and adding them to the crawled index of SP.  Then, create a content type out of the exposed objects.  And finally, add a custom search result template for the content type.  MSDN will be your friend on this and so will your SP administrator.

Comment: I have gone down the same route in my design, and think this is the best and easiest solution. This answer provides a lot of valuable concepts and will help me going forward. Thanks!